# Error Attempting to Bind EJB in WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.8

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere-liberty

Background: I am inheriting an ancient application that utilizes EJBs. In the facet of the project it lists as a 3.0 EJB.  The EJB was written while running WebSphere 6.1 where we had two jvms, one for UI/Presentation Layer and a second JVM that hosted the EJB / "data layer" which is also using JPA.  We are moving to WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.8 and when I start my application and access it, I get the following exception:

```
....
Caused by: 
com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/ejb/CHServiceBean reference.  The exception message was: CWNEN1003E: The server was unable to find the com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote binding with the com.xxx.xxx.service.CHService type for the java:comp/env/ejb/CHServiceBean reference.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1458)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejb.injection.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1047)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1389)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.naming.InjectionJavaColonHelper.getObjectInstance(InjectionJavaColonHelper.java:116)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: 
com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN1003E: The server was unable to find the com.xxx.xxxx.service.CHServiceRemote binding with the com.xxx.xxxxx.service.CHService type for the java:comp/env/ejb/CHServiceBean reference.
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(IndirectJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:202)
```

Here is the code that is accessing the context object:
The supplied String jndiName that is failing is:
"java:comp/env/ejb/CHServiceBean"

```
public Object getResource(String jndiName) throws Exception {
    Object obj = null;
    if (obj == null) {
        try {
            obj = new InitialContext().lookup(jndiName);
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XXXXXX.error("ServiceLocator.getResource(...) ERROR, "");
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

We have two packaged EAR files, Ear file A called (CHNew.ear) which contains a .war called CHNew.war that contains most of the front end logic and in the deployment assembly references the CHService.jar file. Ear file B called (CHService.ear) houses the EJB code in a war project called CHService.war. They both reside on the same application server and thus the same jvm but are obviously not packaged in the same ear file.

Ear A has the following web.xml snippet:

```
<ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1430884948507">
  <description>
  </description>
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/CHServiceBean</ejb-ref-name>
  <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
  <home>com.xxx.xxx.service.CHService</home>
  <remote>com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote</remote>
</ejb-ref>
<ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1430885115133">
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/CHServiceBeanRO</ejb-ref-name>
  <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
  <home>com.xxx.xxxx.service.CHServiceRO</home>
  <remote>com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemoteRO</remote>
</ejb-ref>
```

**EDIT:**  Here is the contents of the  ibm-web-bnx.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1430419801447" virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
  <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1430749102271" jndiName="services/cache/CHContacts">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_1430749102271"/>
  </resRefBindings>
  <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1436377001246" jndiName="jdbc/nextgen">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_1436377001246"/>
  </resRefBindings>
  <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1436377001247" jndiName="jdbc/nextgen_RO">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_1436377001247"/>
  </resRefBindings>
  <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1456409466488" jndiName="services/cache/CHGeneric">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_1456409466488"/>
  </resRefBindings>
  <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1430884948507" jndiName="com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote">
    <bindingEjbRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#EjbRef_1430884948507"/>
  </ejbRefBindings>
  <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1430885115133" jndiName="com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemoteRO">
    <bindingEjbRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#EjbRef_1430885115133"/>
  </ejbRefBindings>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

*There are binding .xmi (note not .xml) files from the past which I believe are ignored?

In the Ear App B there is an ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file that contains the following stanza:

```
<session name="CHServiceBean">
  <resource-ref name="jdbc/db" binding-name="jdbc/db"></resource-ref>
  <resource-ref name="services/cache/CacheA" binding-name="services/cache/CHBluepages"></resource-ref>
  <resource-ref name="services/cache/CacheB" binding-name="services/cache/CHGeneric" ></resource-ref>
</session>

<session name="CHServiceBeanRO">
  <resource-ref name="jdbc/db_RO"
      binding-name="jdbc/db_RO">
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref name="jdbc/db" binding-name="jdbc/db"></resource-ref>
  <resource-ref name="services/cache/CHGeneric" binding-name="services/cache/CHGeneric"></resource-ref>
  <resource-ref name="services/cache/CacheA" binding-name="services/cache/CacheB"></resource-ref>
</session>
```

Here is my Liberty server.xml file:

```
<!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature> 
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>usr:webCacheMonitor-1.0</feature>
        <feature>webCache-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!--  Admin Center Config Start -->
    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="xxxxxx"/> 

    <basicRegistry id="basic"> 
          <user name="wpsadmin" password="xxxxxx"/> 
    </basicRegistry> 

    <administrator-role> 
      <user>wpsadmin</user>
    </administrator-role>

    <remoteFileAccess> 
       <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir> 
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <enterpriseApplication id="CHNewCHRDMEAR" location="CHNewCHRDMEAR.ear" name="CHNewCHRDMEAR">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="AllAuthenticated">
                <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/>
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
    </enterpriseApplication>
    <enterpriseApplication id="CHServiceEAR" location="CHServiceEAR.ear" name="CHServiceEAR"/>

    <!--  JAAS Authentication Alias (Global) Config -->
    <authData id="r4dba" password="{xor}MzhmJT06ajI=" user="r4dba"/>

    <!--  JDBC Driver and Datasource Config -->
    <library id="DB2JCC4Lib">
        <fileset dir="C:\DB2\Jars" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"/>
    </library>
</server>
```

Questions:

1. What else do I need to do to bind this EJB?
2. I have tried using the java:global namespace to reference the two EJBs (in the same EJB applcation) with the following JNDI names (which all threw JNDI naming exceptions):

   1. java:global/CHServiceEAR/CHService/CHServiceBean!com.xxx.xxx.service.CHSerivceBean
   2. java:global/CHServiceEAR/CHService/CHServiceBean

Comment: When you deploy your EARs, Websphere doesn't print the JNDI contexts to the server console or log file?

Comment: I am in a development env in Liberty, you essentially drop the ears (or use Add / Remove Apps) and Liberty loads them. As far as I can see it doesn't dump the namepsace to a log. I added the following to my server.xml to enable jndi tracing:
<logging  traceSpecification="Naming=all:NamingService=all"
  traceFileName="jndi.log"
  maxFileSize="20"
  maxFiles="10"
  traceFormat="BASIC"
 />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, but you need to show the ibm-web-bnd.xml from CHNew.war.  The error message suggests you have a binding configured like:

```
<ejb-ref name="ejb/CHServiceBean" binding-name="com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote">
```

...or something like this if you're using ibm-web-bnd.xmi:

```
  <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1430884948507" jndiName="com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote">
    <bindingEjbRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#EjbRef_1430884948507"/>
  </ejbRefBindings>
```

The Liberty profile only binds EJBs to the `java:` namespace and never to the default namespace (which includes names like `com.xxx.xxx.service.CHServiceRemote`), so this lookup will always fail.  See the "Naming" section of the [Using enterprise JavaBeans with remote interfaces on Liberty](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html) topic in the Knowledge Center.  You need to update the binding-name to something like `java:global/CHService/CHService/CHServiceBean`.  See the CNTR0167I message in messages.log for the exact string to use.

Comment: Hi Brett, I added the contents of the ibm-web-bnd.xml file. Are you saying that I need to update the ibm-web-bnd.xml file to utilize the java:global namespace, for example something like this:
<ejb-ref name="ejb/CHServiceBean" binding-name="java:global/CHService/CHService/CHServiceBean">?

Comment: @Doug Well, since you're using ibm-web-bnd.xmi (not .xml), you'll need to update to `jndiName="java:global/CHService/CHService/CHServiceBean"` or so depending on the CNTR0167I message in messages.log, but yes, you need to update that binding name to use `java:global`.  I've updated the answer to give a link to the Knowledge Center where I wrote basically the same thing.  (FYI, you forgot to blind the interface name in your ibm-web-bnd.xmi snippet.)

Comment: all the info helped. After tracking down the messages in the messages.log under the "CNTR0167I" header I found the binding names. I added them to the ibm-web-bnd.xmi file and created an ibm-web-bnd.xml file and added the <ejb-ref> tag pointing to the jndi name. After restart I no longer see the above error. I get a new error related to the persistence service but the original issue is resolved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interesting.  ibm-web-bnd.xmi (with ejbRefBindings) is always used for web 2.x and ibm-web-bnd.xml (with ejb-ref) is always used for web 3.0.  I guess you used to have a web 2.x descriptor and you've since upgraded it to 3.0.  If you were to deploy the app to full profile, it would give a warning about the mismatched 3.0 with .xmi, but I guess Liberty profile doesn't warn about that (yet?).